# Rewrite Query String with Apache

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to rewrite a query string:

from: domain.com/new-arrival.htm?webcat=1

to: domain.com/men-new-arrivals

This is what I have so far which doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^webcat=1$
RewriteRule ^new-arrival\.htm$ /men-new-arrivals? [R=301]
```

Thanks